# Python error on previously working model

Tags: qgis, python, error, qgis-modeler

I have a model built that's adding columns to a vector layer and creating a fixed width buffer layer.  Everything was working fine, but now when I go to edit the model it won't open and I'm receiving the following python error...

[image: python error]

Comment: Please include the error as text, preferably formatted as code. That way it will be easier to read and for others to find this question via search engines.